# How to setup Wordpress with https://box.scotch.io/?

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

I have setup scotch box and now trying to setup WordPress with scotch box how would I go by doing this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently set this up.

To set up Wordpress, place the Wordpress install files inside the scotch/public folder that is created when you first run scotch.io

You will then need to ssh into your vagrant box, and set up a new MySQL database.  You can import a dump via the command line, or export/import using Sequel like I did.

Even though mod_rewrite is already enabled in scotch.io, I found it helpful to restart the apache2 server in the vagrant box.

Once that's done - you should be able to navigate to 192.168.33.10 on your browser to see your install.

Set the wp_config.php database host to localhost.

I found the following code great for getting permalinks working, place this at the top of your wp_config file:

```
$s = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? '' : ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 
's' : '';
$port = ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '80') ? '' : (":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);
$url = "http$s://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $port;
define('WP_HOME', $url);
define('WP_SITEURL', $url);
unset($s, $port, $url);
```

If you get a Database access error - this is a good sign you're on the right track, you need to put in the user: root / pass: root details fro the vagrant web host to access the database inside the box.